# Haskell: Remembering previous element in a list

Tags: haskell, scope

Simple question, unsure how to do it.

I'm writing a more limited version of the sum function from Data.List, and have the following code:

```
-- Sum the contents of a list

sum' :: Num a => [a] -> a

sum' [] = 0

sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' rest where
              rest = drop (succ (elemIndex x xs)) xs
```

I believe this would work if the *x* argument of elemIndex was in scope of the current list element.

I want to do this without using Foldable, as basic as possible, since it is a problem in Graham Hutton's *Programming in Haskell* expected to be written before he covers Foldable, or most Haskell ideas.

Comment: This is the exact situation to use a fold. I would consider a fold to be a "primitive".

Comment: To sum a list, it's just `foldl + numbers`. Folds are incredibly simple once you use them a few times.

Comment: Are you just trying to sum a list of numbers? I'll write an answer if that's your question. It's unclear though exactly what you're going for.

Comment: Sum the numbers in a list, yes. I was supposed to be able to solve this before learning Foldable. I also just learned the (+1) trick in place of the succ function. I'd love an answer, would clear the post.

Comment: Can you explain what you aim to achieve with the `drop (succ (elemIndex x xs)) xs` part?

Comment: It's like tail, but variable with x?

Comment: Your questions states that your function should "Sum the contents of a list". However, it is very clearly intended to do something else. It is adding *some* of the elements of the list, but not all. `drop (succ (elemIndex x xs)) xs` doesn't even typecheck (`elemIndex` produces `Maybe Int`). If that part did work, it would remove the prefix of `xs` which comes before another occurrence of `x` (and do .. something when `x` is not in `xs`). Can you describe the intended semantics of `sum'` correctly?

Comment: To address some more concrete issues here: "Note how rest is a set" - is it? It looks like a plain old list. "not being built by an explicit notation" ... " - what is 'explicit notation'? Is it relevant to the question? "Instead it is out of scope." - It sounds like your code is presently giving you an error. You should include that error in your question. (I see no scope errors here). "I've seen a similar question or two" - if your question has already been asked and answered, can you change the focus of this question to what you don't understand about those answers?

Comment: What do you mean by "[x] is out of scope"?

Comment: Edited. It was hard to read, and wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a summing function "manually", it would simply be the first element plus the sum of the remaining elements:

```
sum' :: Num a => [a] -> a

-- The sum of an empty list is 0
-- The "base case" of the recursion
sum' [] = 0

-- The sum of a non-empty list is equal to the first element
-- plus the sum of the rest of the list 
sum' (x:xs) = x + (sum' xs)
```

Which is nice, but after a while, you'll realize you'll be doing this exact pattern a lot: looping over a list while maintaining an accumulator. The sum of the numbers is the accumulator in this case.

This is where `fold`s come in. A complete description of how a fold works is beyond the question, but to sum a list of numbers using a fold, you can simply write:

```
sum' :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum' xs = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

Folds *basically* insert the function you give it between each element in the list, so

```
foldl (+) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is *basically* the same thing as (note the 0 on the left. That's the starting sum):

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

For more on folds, I wrote an answer (among many others) [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/331544/139925). It's worth a look.

Comment: 1. Your explanation of foldl is excellent 2. I didn't realize it could be written so simply as your first answer. 3. The Haskell community appears to be alot more understanding than many others! I was expecting to be downvoted into oblivion. Instead, I got a good answer and learned something. Thank you

Comment: Np. I should note though that the function you give to `foldl` doesn't need to be as simple as a math operator. Folds + anonymous functions = very succinct looping.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand currying you can simply it even more:

```
sum' = foldl (+) 0
```